# I've employee_roles table it stores many organization id in one row by array

Tags: sql, json, oracle

the column names along with the sample values from the **`employee_roles`** table:

```
user_id : "1"
org_id : ["1", "2"]
```

I want to get org_id and org_name by one row with user_id
please help me?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` statement for your table; the `INSERT` statements for some sample data; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution; and the expected output for that sample data. At the moment, both the table structure and the expected output are ambiguous from your description and the question is not answerable (especially as you want `org_name` but no data exists for that).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`JSON_TABLE()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) function, if the currently used DB version is at least `12.1.0.2`, in order to return the values row-wise such as

```
 SELECT user_id, j.org_id
   FROM employee_roles , 
        JSON_TABLE(org_id, '$'
                        COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                                 COLUMNS (
                                          org_id VARCHAR2 PATH '$'
                                         ) 
                                 ) 
                  ) j
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BL6r6bp5)</kbd>